# Converting doc to pdf using Interop.Word C#

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop, filesystemwatcher

I'm using C# to convert the .doc to .pdf. The .doc is on the vendor's site. To get the .doc, we have to click on a button which presents us with option to `Open, Save, or Cancel`. When the user clicks on `Save` button, it prompts for the location. The user chooses the location in mapped drive, say, `S:\Some Folder\abc.doc`, and the actual folder location is `\\server\\folder\Some Folder`. This is where my program comes in to play. I'm using `FileSystemWatcher` class in c# with Filter set for .doc files. I can see in debug that the file is found. The folder location is hardcoded and saved as the actual folder location mentioned above. The user and the application has full permission to the folder. However, I'm getting `FileNotFoundException` when I run the program.

This is what I have

```
        WriteToFile("Starting Word application");
        Application word = new Application();

        object missing = Type.Missing;

        var sourcefile = new FileInfo(path);

        // check if the created file ends with .doc. 
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(path);
        if (!path.ToLower().EndsWith(".doc"))
        {
            return "";
        }

        word.Visible = false;

        WriteToFile("Opening doc as read only");
        // open readonly            
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sourcefile.FullName);
        var doc = word.Documents.Open(FileName: sourcefile.FullName, ReadOnly: true);
```

The strange thing is `sourcefile.FullName` doesn't show the hard coded server address that `path` is set to. It shows the file path as `S:\Some Folder\abc.doc`, which makes no sense to me. What's going on here, and why can't it find the file?

Comment: Does it work as expected in the IDE if you wait a few seconds after the FSW event but before the code above runs?

Comment: I haven't tried that. I will right now. But, what's baffling more is that even when I'm providing source file hardcoded as "\\server\... ", the debugger still tells me that it can't find `S:\Some Folder\abc.doc`. My program knows nothing about S drive. So, how is it picking that up, unless it's reading the file attribute from the file name itself which it found, right?

Comment: @AlexK. You were right. I had to wait a few seconds after the FSW event. I added Thread.Sleep(5000) before the code ran and after FSW OnCreated event was fired. That worked flawlessly. Sorry, it took me a while to work on it. Could you please add your comment as Answer so that I can mark it as correct answer? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OnCreate` event can fire when the underlying file is still in use/being written to which can cause problems if you immediately try to access it.

The simple solution is to introduce either an arbitrary delay to allow for the file to be closed by the process creating it, or better a loop with a short delay that attempts to access the file, catches the relevant exception should it occur  and retries.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you use the wrong FileInfo object. Try to generate an new one or use

```
System.IO.Path.Combine(@"\\server\folder\Some Folder", "sourcefile.Name")
```

which you could also use to generate your new FileInfo Object. The object which you are using is probably the one of the user dialogue box which is using the mapped drive. You do also have a typo in your location. `\\SERVERNAME\\` isn't an UNC path. There should be only two backslashes on the beginning of the string. It should be

```
@"\\server\folder\Some Folder"

WriteToFile("Starting Word application");
Application word = new Word.Application();

object missing = Type.Missing;

var sourcefile = new System.IO.FileInfo(path);
string SomeShare = @"\\SomeServer\Someshare\Somepath";
System.IO.FileInfo WorkFile = new System.IO.FileInfo(System.IO.Path.Combine(SomeShare, sourcefile.Name));

// check if the created file ends with .doc. 
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(path);
if (!path.ToLower().EndsWith(".doc"))
{
     return "";
}

word.Visible = false;

WriteToFile("Opening doc as read only");
// open readonly            
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sourcefile.FullName);
var doc = word.Documents.Open(FileName: WorkFile.FullName, ReadOnly: true);
}
```

This works just fine for me, it updates the path to the correct UNC pattern. If the file still isn't accesible you should check if you can open it on the workstation using the UNC path you have generated.

Comment: `\\SERVERANAME\\` was just a typo. I implemented your suggestion, but even with that I'm still getting the same error message. And, it's still picking the mapped drive instead of the actual server location. I don't understand. And the file exists.

Comment: Updated my answer with a full example using your snippet. I'm still convinced that you are passing the path of the dialogue box for the user input to your path variable. Which results in this error in the first place.

Comment: I don't know if I can call it passing the path of the dialog box. Because, the path is set as "\\servername\folder.." to Path of `FileSystemWatcher` class. And, I'm using `OnCreate(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)` with `sourcepath = e.FullPath`. If e.FullPath is causing this issue, then I don't know about it. Otherwise, there's nowhere where the code knows about "S:\" other than the fact that S drive is mapped on the developer machine. I didn't think that mattered. Well, it doesn't matter, if the user opens the document and Clicks 'Save As", then the program has no error, has other.